# Bootstrap confidence interval for correlation of two time series

Tags: r, statistics

I have two time series (ts_a and ts_b) and I would like to get bootstrap confidence intervals for correlation between the two series (in R). Any suggestion about how to proceed?

Thanks ind advance

Answer (score -1):

This is not my code and you can find the original [here](http://www.math.montana.edu/jobo/st446/documents/bootcorr.r)

```
require(boot)
xy <- data.frame(cbind(ts_a,ts_b))
```

`# Bootstrap the Pearson correlation coefficient`

```
pearson <- function(d,i=c(1:dim(xy)[1]){
        d2 <- d[i,]
        return(cor(d2$ts_a,d2$ts_b))
     }
bootcorr <- boot(data=xy,statistic=pearson,R=999)
bootcorr
#Making a result table for output using 95% BCa CI
resultTable <- summary(bootcorr)
resultTable <- cbind(resultTable , CI95pc = NA)
for (i in 1:dim(resultTable )[1]) {
##Extracting CI from boot.ci output
  a <- boot.ci(bootcorr,index = i, conf=.95, type = 'bca')$bca[4:5]
##Adding the CI to your output table
  resultTable $CI95pc[i] <- paste(round(a[1],3),"-",round(a[2],3),sep=" ")
  rm(a)
}
print(resultTable)
```

Comment: If at all possible please include some explanation why this code might help OP with his problem.

Comment: You should not use the ordinary bootstrap for time series. One alternative is the block bootstrap: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/boot/versions/1.3-20/topics/tsboot